# what is the xpath for crawl some data on newzealand.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Wonder whether anyone could tell how to select xpath on http://www.newzealand.com/int/new-zealand/? For example:

```
//*[@id="tabsetitem-2327405-1388181"]/div[2]/div/h5/a
```

I couldn't get the data in response.xpath using above selector, could someone please help out?

Thanks a lot, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Approaching to web-scrape this particular page would not be easy. The site is quite dynamic and the page load and construction involves XHR requests and javascript executed by the browser. Scrapy is not a browser, there is no javascript engine inside it, *you only get the initial HTML page, which does not contain the search results*:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.newzealand.com/int/new-zealand/
In [1]: response.xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "tabset-results")]').extract()[0]
Out[1]: u'<div class="tabset__results" id="tabset-results-2327405">\r\n</div>'
```

Note that instead you might want to use [the API, provided by newzealand.com](http://www.newzealand.com/us/utilities/web-services/).